# What do you mean by "byte equivalent" ?

Tags: assembly, byte, nasm, ambiguity, mov

I am bit new to assembly language and having difficulty understanding the term "byte equivalent".

It is used in the following context :-
The MOV instruction causes ambiguity at times. For example, look at the statements:

```
MOV  EBX, [MY_TABLE]  ; Effective Address of MY_TABLE in EBX
MOV  [EBX], 110       ; MY_TABLE[0] = 110
```

It is not clear whether you want to move a byte equivalent or word equivalent of the number 110. In such cases, it is wise to use a type specifier.

The link to the tutorial is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm)

It would be a great help if anybody could explain the term byte equivalent and  provide with a clear situation in which "type specifiers" may come in handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means that the size of `110` is ambiguous in the instruction `MOV  [EBX], 110`. There's no way of telling just by looking at that instruction if you intended to store the 8-bit (byte equivalent) value `0x6E`, the 16-bit (word equivalent) value `0x006E` or the 32-bit (dword equivalent) value `0x0000006E`.

A size specifier would be used to tell the assembler how to interpret the instruction, and the exact syntax for such specifiers depends on which assembler you use. In NASM syntax you'd say `mov byte [ebx],110` to specify that you wanted to store a byte. In MASM/TASM syntax you'd say `mov byte ptr [ebx],110`.